# Reading in a list of values into a Python variable (or variables)

Tags: python

If you look at the site [Code Abbey](https://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_list) you'll see a list of simple tasks to be solved in programming. Typically they ask for something simple like finding the minimum of three numbers, and you're given a list of twenty-five to thirty sets of numbers to process.

```
8258665 -1509184 -1150960
6426035 -8744356 -3699930
-5253083 -3480272 -195609
-9613917 -4137099 3192037
```

I'm looking for a way to take these three lists and insert them into three lists that I can then process. I'm a beginner at all this and have to manually paste the numbers in and do lots of deletions and adding of commas to manually make three lists. But there has to be a better way.

Some of the programs I've seen use `input().strip` or `input.slice()` (I don't remember exactly) to process the numbers, but I can't see their complete solutions so can't see their complete logic.

You can't save these to an external file and read them in. My thought was to make a text file and read them in that way. No dice -- the way the answers are processed has you run your code in their page, and your answer is automatically put in the answer slot. But that's too much detail.

I want to know if there is a way in Python to have a list of numbers like I have above just pasted into a Python program and then read them into a python data structure. The `input()` methods don't make sense to me as I thought `input()` was for keyboard input. And in none of my reading have I seen a way to have data just splatted into a script for processing. Since these are on the very simplest problems, the Code Abbey people must think it something really easy to do and I just don't see it.

Comment: Just copy and paste this as a multi-line string, then do `data = list(map(int, data.split()))`

Comment: Can you give an example, though? I think they provide this data as text to standard input, hence the use of `input()`

Comment: There’s an example at the link I provided (I think).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your mentioned question. you can append `list_i` into some other list in order to solve exact mentioned question.

```
number_of_list = int(input()) # take number of lists in input in first line.
for i in range(number_of_list):
    list_i = list(map(int, input().split())) # this will map all values into INT and put them into a list.
    print(min(list_i))
```

Comment: I don’t see where the list of numbers should be placed in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given a string separated with spaces (which is what you showed) we can do this to turn it into a list:

```
myString = input() #This is where you input your numbers, simply separated by spaces
myArray = myString.split() #This separates your string into a list of strings
myArray = [int(s) for s in myArray] #This uses turns the list of strings into a list of integers
```

From there, you'll have a list of integers to work with

Comment: If you don’t mind, could you tell me where the actual list of numbers goes? That’s the problem I had with their help: code, but no info on what to do with the actual numbers.

Comment: The call to `input()` in the first line is where you type in your list. You could also replace it with a string and be just fine. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to read in multiline input, you can read each line individually and then convert each line to an array of ints:

```
def create_list():
    lines = []
    print('Paste the input below or enter it line by line:')
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break

    return [list(map(int, line.split(' '))) for line in lines]
```

Using this you can copy and paste your input and get the output you want:

```
>>> nums = create_list()
Paste the input below or enter it line by line:
8258665 -1509184 -1150960
6426035 -8744356 -3699930
-5253083 -3480272 -195609
-9613917 -4137099 3192037

>>> nums
[[8258665, -1509184, -1150960], [6426035, -8744356, -3699930], [-5253083, -3480272, -195609], [-9613917, -4137099, 3192037]]
```

What this line `[list(map(int, line.split(' '))) for line in lines]` is doing is the following:

- It iterates through each line in the lines list (`for line in lines`)
- It splits each line into a list using a space as a delimiter (`line.split(' ')`)
- It maps a function call to each element to replace each value of the passed list with the result of calling the function on the value, in this case it replaces each result with its conversion from a `str` to an `int` by calling `int()` on each element of `line.split(' ')` (`map(int, line.split(' ')`)
- Then it converts this returned `map` iterator to a `list`, producing the value you want

That line would be roughly equivalent to the following:

```
for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    split_line = line.split(' ')
    for idx2, el in enumerate(split_line):
        split_line[idx2] = int(el)

    lines[idx] = split_line

return lines
```

Comment: Your return line, with map, int, and split, looks quite complicated (and beyond me). Strange that they thought I could do this when the problem was as simple as adding two numbers together.

Comment: @SciolismApparently it is a bit complicated, but I updated my answer to more clearly explain what's happening in that line. I wrote it like this to make it more compact, but the actual logic behind it is not too complicated and could be accomplished with a for loop

Comment: @SciolismApparently I also added another snippet which shows how to accomplish that in a more readable fashion